# is 'B' class impact resistance of safety glasses sufficient for Airsoft?

Tags: equipment, airsoft

I have access to various work safety equipment for very reasonable prices. That includes various protective glasses/goggles, face plates etc.

These are standarized according to EN166 norm. Obviously, "F" class, "Low-energy impact, velocity 45m/s" is insufficient.

The problem is the definitely sufficient "A" class (High-energy impact, velocity 190m/s) is mostly restricted to rather expensive and somewhat unwieldy face plates, while "B" (Medium-energy impact, velocity 120m/s) offers a range of very reasonably priced, nice glasses and goggles.

I have no clue how the BB energy converts to these requirements - is "B" class safe enough, or should I choose between "A" and dedicated Airsoft goggles?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is *don't risk it*.

You only have one set of eyes, so you should look after them well. This means buying goggles *intended for airsoft*. Things like ski goggles (I don't know what grade they come around at) get shot out easily.

The advice that "anything plastic will work" is bad advice, so you should always take proper precautions. Get goggles with the purpose of protecting your eyes from 700fps and up.

If you're interested in keeping your teeth and lower face intact, you might want to invest in a lower face mask (a good mesh one goes for about 10-15 GBP from most retailers.

So yeah-- I'd recommend buying purpose-build products.

**EDIT:** You asked what to buy, and I suggest the best that you can afford (within reason, of course.) I have a set of £60 goggles, although that price is mainly because they fit over my glasses.

Answer (score -6):

It depends on the FPS of the gun but typically anything plastic is sufficient. Ive seen swimming goggles to workshop goggles to oakley glasses (pellets may scratch these though). They all work fine. Just cover the eyes. Anyway, Airsoft pellets don't carry too much kinetic energy.

Comment: In outdoor games you can expect even 700FPS; "typically anything plastic is sufficient" is fundamentally wrong and actively dangerous advice; Any F class and "unrated" plastic glasses WILL shatter at impact and may lead to serious eye injury.

Comment: AS SF says the anything plastic is actively dangerous, just because you have seen things work fine doesnt mean they always will.  Oakley for example have shotgunned their lenses and they survived however thats not a wise choice.

Comment: Based on previous comments, **DISCLAIMER: DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME**